# How can I prevent jQuery dialog closing immediately if i click on Edit or Delete button?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

If I click "Add new" button it opens a jQuery dialog containing a GridView with Edit and Delete buttons
Which have the full code behind functionalities. If I click on “Edit” button the jQuery dialog disappears.
I am not able to edit.

If I click again "Add new" button it opens jQuery dialog with “update, cancel”.

How can I prevent jQuery dialog closing immediately if i click on Edit or Delete button?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $("[id*=btnPopup]").live("click", function (ev) {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
    title: "Add new",
    width: 1200,
    height: 500,
    modal: true,
    open: function (type, data) {
    $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
      },
     buttons: { 
       Close: function () {
       $(this).dialog('close');
          dialog.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
       }
      }             
   });

    return false;
   });

</script>

.aspx file
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
<asp:GridView ID="gridViewShowVariables" runat="server" ......>
 </asp:GridView>
<div/>
<asp:Button ID="btnPopup" runat="server" Text="`enter code here`Add new item" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're finding some of the limitations of the ASP.NET postback model. When you click a button, it causes a postback to the server, meaning the page must be entirely resent and you'll lose the client side state. So what you can do is [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx) and re-open the dialog so that when the page is sent back to the client after postback, the dialog will open back up again.

--Update--

First, let's change how you declare the dialog.

```
$("[id*=btnPopup]").live("click", function (ev) {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
    title: "Add new",
    width: 1200,
    height: 500,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    appendTo: "form",
     buttons: { 
       Close: function () {
       $(this).dialog('close');
          dialog.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first")); //I think this can be eliminated too.
       }
      }             
   });
```

Then, when you want to open it, do this:

```
$("[id*=btnPopup]").live("click", function (ev) {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Now, any time your cause a postback, and you want to leave the dialog open after the postback, do this on the server side:

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method (this.GetType(), "open-dialog", "$('#dialog').dialog('open');", true);
```

--End Update--

Alternatively you could use an UpdatePanel for partial postbacks. But I don't recommend those, because they tend to cause more problems than they solve.

My top recommendation is to switch off GridView to a regular table, then use AJAX to send updates back to the server.

Comment: I tried with ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "Script", "document.getElementById('" + panelDialogContent.ClientID + "').style.display='" + strBlockNone + "';", false); did not help inside gridview editmethod. my div dialog is inside a panel "panelDialogContent"

Comment: The code you just posted would hide it. You want to show it, ex: `$("#selector").dialog("open");`

Comment: @Husso Oh, and you should also probably declare it as a dialog on document ready, rather than when you open it. That way you don't have to redeclare it as a dialog. And you don't have to do that awkward append the parent to the form thing when you declare it as a dialog. Just use the `appendTo: "form"` option, as described on their [API page](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo).

Comment: Do you mean in ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock or in  $("#dialog").dialog({
    title: "Add new", .......
Thanks

Comment: I added  $("#dialog").dialog({

    title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
    width: 1200,
    height: 500,
    appendTo: "form", .....  but still the same issue

Comment: @Husso Please add the code that I described in my answer.

Comment: ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "open-dialog", "$('#dialog').dialog('open');'", true);
 highlights "no verload for  method RegisterStartupScript takes 5 argments"                                                            Thanks

Comment: here is the updated code               
$("[id*=btnPopup]").live("click", function () { 
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    title: "Add new",
    width: 1200,
    height: 500,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    appendTo: "form",
    buttons: { 
 Close: function () {
  $(this).dialog('close');        }
 }             
 });
 });
 $("[id*=btnPopup]").live("click", function (ev) {
   $("#dialog").dialog("open");
 });

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "open-dialog", "$('#dialog').dialog('open');", true);  the modal dialog disappears immediately hanks

Comment: Mason, please have a look at the code in my answer. dialog shows and disappears immediatelly

Comment: @Husso The error you're getting doesn't go with the code you just provided. `ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "open-dialog", "$('#dialog').dialog('open');'", true);` is only 4 arguments, not 5. I suspect you have a copy paste error. Also, please format your code in comments using backticks (just above the tab key on most keyboards)

Comment: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "msgbox", "$('#dialog').dialog('open');", true);   in gridview1_RowCommand but it still shows the dialog and disappears if i click on btnPopup

Comment: Do you get a client side JavaScript error? Did you make sure the the code that registers the startup script is actually hit on post back?

Comment: I do not get any error just as i mentioned before if i hit the btnPopup button the dialog shows maybe 2 secs then the jQuery dialog disappears. I am new to jQuery i guess it's something i still miss Thanks

Comment: When it disappears, does it post back to the server? Also, you didn't answer all the questions from my previous comment.

Comment: yes I have this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "script1", "$('#dialog').dialog('open');", true); in form load

Comment: Mason, it posts back to the server but if I click on the btnPopup button the modal dialog shows and disappears. Do you have any idea what is missing?    Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `beforeClose` event to prevent the dialog from closing.

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    beforeClose: function(){
        if(error == 1){
            alert('error');
            return false;
        } 
    }
});
```

or you can also use the close event:

```
$(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
          close: function(event,ui){
              $(this).dialog('open');
          }
      });
  });
```

Comment: That won't work in an ASP.NET environment where clicking a button will cause a postback to the server in most situations.

Comment: ASP.NET was not mentioned in the original question.

Comment: Yup, I missed the tag, sorry. But the markup was pure jQuery in the original question :)